# Pass Local Variable in SweetAlert2 PreConfirm - Angular 7

Tags: angular, typescript, sweetalert2

I have the following `.ts` file

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-product-category',
  templateUrl: './product-category.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./product-category.component.css']
})
export class ProductCategoryComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(public httpClient: HttpClient) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {   
  }

  delete(name, id) {
    Swal.fire({
      title: 'Are you sure?',
      text: 'Do you want to delete Product Category - ' + name + '?',
      type: 'warning',
      showCancelButton: true,
      showLoaderOnConfirm: true,
      confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
      cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
      confirmButtonText: 'Yes, delete it!',
      preConfirm(inputValue: any): Promise<any | void> | any | void {
          // I want to use httpClient to make a http request to the server here
          this.httpClient.delete()...;
      }
    }).then((result) => {
      if (result.value) {
        Swal.fire(
          'Deleted!',
          'Your file has been deleted.',
          'success'
        );
      }
    });
  }
}
```

I want to use the `httpClient` defined in the constructor to make a network call inside the `preConfirm` code block but I can't reference the variable (httpClient). How do I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use arrow function:

```
preConfirm: (inputValue: any) => {
  this.httpClient.delete(...)
}
```

Comment: This kinda works but I am unable to pass the result to the `.then((result) =>` section. I want the `Alert` to be shown based on what the server responds.

Comment: `this.httpClient.delete(...).subscribe(response ==> Swal.fire(// what you want based on response))`